# Question about integral

Tags: integration

I want to prove the inversion theorem on $R^{k}$.Then I need to compute the integral :

$\int_{R^{1}}\exp^{-\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}+itx}dx$

I have no ideal how to deal with it.I will appreciate your help.

Comment: What is $R^1$?${}$

Comment: $a,t$ is real parameter.

Comment: What are the integration limits ? $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,\infty)$ ?

Comment: $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: I want to prove the inversion theorem of Fourier Transform on $L^{1}(R^{k})$ so I imitate the proof of inversion theorem on $L^{1}(R^{1})$ .In that proof,it chooses auxiliary functions $\exp^{-|t|}$.